# Installing Xdebug, PEAR, Pecl on Mavericks

Tags: php, osx-mavericks, pear, xdebug, pecl

I'm having a real problem figuring out how to install PEAR, XDebug, and PECL on my local Mac upgraded from Mountain Lion to Mavericks.

I run `which php` and get `/usr/bin/php`

When I do `php --interactive` I get the message:

```
Failed loading /usr/bin/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/bin/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _output_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

When I try to install PEAR I first cd to `/usr/lib/php` and from there run the command :

```
$ sudo php -d detect_unicode=0 go-pear.phar
Failed loading /usr/bin/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/bin/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _output_globals
      Referenced from: /usr/bin/xdebug.so
      Expected in: flat namespace

    Could not open input file: go-pear.phar
```

I've also tried `sudo pecl install xdebug` and get:

```
-could not open input file :
/usr/lib/php/pear/peclcmd.php
```

to me this means these tools were installed once, and are on a system path, but when I look at my $PATH variable, they aren't explicitly named.

Since I'm running Google App Engine and python via macports and have homebrew installed, I'm having a tough time tracking down what needs to change, and whether or not I have multiple installations of PHP - one running from terminal that may not be the same as the one my apache server is using for localhost serving.

How can I figure out which versions of PHP I'm running, which ones need to be updated, and how to update them so I can use Xdebug, PEAR and PECL?

Comment: I'm confused - did you download go-pear.phar to /usr/lib/php or was it there already? You will most likely need to download it from http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar using curl - $ curl -O http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar ; also it appears that you don't yet have xdebug installed properly.

Comment: Here's the thing: I have xdebug installed properly for Komodo to do remote debugging on a remote server - works remarkably well. However, when I run PHP locally (even with Komodo) it doesn't work.

Comment: I went ahead and installed from `/usr/lib/php` and PEAR and PECL are now both accessible. Still getting the same xdebug.so error: 
`MacBookPro:php jon$ php --interactive
Failed loading /usr/bin/xdebug.so:  dlopen(/usr/bin/xdebug.so, 9): Symbol not found: _output_globals
  Referenced from: /usr/bin/xdebug.so
  Expected in: flat namespace`

Comment: I also am having this problem. I will keep checking to see if anyone has answered in another post, but the Xdebug, PEAR, PECL is the exact issue I'm having. Actually, I'm getting this error:

Could not open input file: go-pear.phar

Comment: I never solved this problem. I believe the root of the issue is having multiple versions of PHP installed via Macports, and not knowing how to configure my system properly. Instead, I've gone with MAMP, which has Xdebug installed by default, and am successfully debugging in Komodo, on localhost.